# stop triggering event on child if put on parent

Tags: jquery

if i put event on parent then it also trigger on its child. how to stop trigger event on child

http://jsfiddle.net/nsoni/XLHKL/1/ is fiddle.

jquery:

```
$('.ful').on('click',function(){
    $('ul').show();
});
$('.ful').dblclick(function(){
    $('ul').hide();
});
$('.ful').mouseenter(function(e){
    $('.tip').show();
});
$('.ful').mouseout(function(e){
    $('.tip').hide();
});
$('ul').mouseenter(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('.tip').hide();
});
```

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/XLHKL/2/?

Comment: Stop what on what? Be more specific. I am guessing you wanted `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` provided you add `e` to the mouseenter function

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are asking, why can't people write good questions?

Events are propagated from the child to the parent, so your desire to stop the event chain from parent to child is not possible.  Adding this stopped the dbl-click from collapsing the `<ul>`.   Add the `event` argument to your events and call `.stopPropagation();`

```
$('.ful ul').dblclick(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation()
});
```